# mysql limitation varchar memory

Tags: mysql

Are some differents in stored memory between varchar(30) and varchar(255) for example in creating tables if fields adapts to number of letters.

Example:

I have created two tables with one field name, in first table name is varchar(255), in the second it is varchar(30). I store 3 values in both:
-'One'
-'Two'
-'Three'

And the question is, are some differents between these two tables in memory? I have perplexity because in programming languages if I declare type for example INT is always 4 bytes.

Comment: Have a look here: [The CHAR and VARCHAR Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html) (or most of the questions listed under "related" on the right side). In short: storagewise, you can think of `varchar(xx)` as a `string` in a java/pascal-like programming language (lengthindicator at the start, not marked at the end by `0` as in c-like languages). `(xx)` is "just" a constraint that checks the length, that has nothing to do with storage (well, apart from the additional length byte when you cross the 255-char-barrier). "Just" in `""`, because constraints are important in databases.

Comment: thanks for the answer